# Private value of a Scala class is not accessible in the companion Object

Tags: scala, class, companion-object

I have a Scala class and it's companion object (in Client.scala) as follows:

```
class Client(val key: Int) {
     private val num_bits = 5
}

object Client {
     val count_entries = Math.pow(2, num_bits).toInt
     println(count_entries)
}
```

However, it throws an error in the Client Object that `not found: value num_bits`. Could someone help?

Comment: I think, I found the reason: I might need to create an instance of the class in order to access it's values. i.e. I am able to access `num_bits` as follows: 
`val bits = new Client(454).num_bits`

Please correct me, if my understanding is wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
class Client(val key: Int) {
     private val num_bits = 5
}

object Client {
     val count_entries = Math.pow(2, new Client(0).num_bits)
     println(count_entries)
}
```

You have to create the object if you want use it.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct. Companion object is a *singleton* object, while classes have *multiple* instances. Therefore you have to have an instance of the class in order to be able to access its fields - otherwise, what instance of the class would `num_bits` in the object refer to?